# Not able to access varaible inside the callback function of onResourceRequested

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

How to pass the variable from outside to `onResourceRequested` function? 
I am not able to access the variable `testvar` inside the callback function of `onResourceRequested` property.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Below is the sample code I used for testing

```
var phantom = require("phantom");

var _ph, _page, _outObj;



phantom.create().then(function(ph){
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then(function(page){
    _page = page;
    var testvar = "WHY THIS IS NOT PRINTING";

    _page.property('onResourceRequested', function (req, networkRequest) {
        console.log("THIS LINE WORKS");
        console.log(testvar); // THIS DOESNT WORK
    }); 

    _page.property('onResourceReceived', function (res) {
         //console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
    });

    return _page.open('https://www.ammaus.com/', function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }
        _ph.exit();
    });

}).then(function(status){
    console.log(status);
    return _page.property('content')
}).then(function(content){
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
}).catch(function(e){
   console.log(e); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function (ES6) like this:

```
_page.property('onResourceRequested', (req, networkRequest) => {
    console.log("THIS LINE WORKS");
    console.log(testvar); // THIS DOESNT WORK
});
```

An arrow function does not newly define its own `this` when it's being executed in the global context; instead, the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used, equivalent to treating this as closure value.

Comment: Didnt work and getting this warning 
warn: Arrow functions such as () => {} are not supported in PhantomJS. Please use function(){} or compile to ES5.